# Start PHP with Swift

Tags: php, swift, web-services, email

I wanted to send an email via a websever and php. Therefore I created a connection to my webserver (000webhoster).
Nearly everything works fine.

My main problem is, that I don't receive anything. I am not even sure, if the PHP code is even executed.

This is my current swift code:

```
func postToServer (){
        print("button pressed")
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.bl1nd3d.herobo.com/email.php")!
        var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)

        var bodyData = "data=something"
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler:{ response, data, error in

            if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode

                if statusCode == 200 {
                    print("nice")
                    // TODO : Sent successfully popup
                }
                else {
                    print(statusCode)
                }
            }


        })

    }
```

This works fine ^^ .. I always receive the statuscode of 200. (If you wanted to try this you need to enable the insecure AppTransport)

And this is my PHP code.. I believe this doesn't work that properly..

```
 <?php

 $postVar = $_POST['data'];

 if (!empty($postVar)) {
     echo $postVar;
     //   email    ,   subject,      message
     mail("myMail@mail.com","Agent was booked","The POST was set and button was pressed" . $postVar);
 }

echo "doesn't work that good " . $postVar;

?>
```

I checked, it should be possible with my webhoster, to send emails..

But it doesn't work.. Did I forget something?

Well something must have gone really bad wrong... My whole dir was deleted while trying this.. :O

> The directory /public_html does not exist or could not be selected, so
>   the directory / is shown instead.

well it probably didn't work that well.. My account was blocked...

Comment: do you check running only the script? maybe you can send mails

Comment: I'm pretty much sure I can send emails. I got somehow blocked for spamreasons..

Comment: what do you mean with "I'm pretty much sure", your script send mails or not. YES or NO.

Comment: yes it sends mails, because I just received an email from my hoster, that I got banned, because of spammails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the spam folder? Standard mail() function is not a great solution to send emails. Your mail provider can block email's sent from mail() or it just couldn't work at all. You need to send mail using smtp. Here's the [example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps)

Comment: I didn't find anything in the spamfolder.. So I believe, they were blocked.. 
Aight, I'm going to try it

Comment: @LucaArchidiacono hope that'll fix your issue.

Comment: yeah I am pretty sure that this will fix it ^^

Comment: @LucaArchidiacono have it fixed your problem?

Comment: yes it was the mail function.. i needed to replace it

Comment: @LucaArchidiacono can you mark my answer as helpful? It's the green checkmark button